# Format string for decimal output

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I just started programming C# today, and I'm trying to get a handle on the format strings.

I would like to output a string of this format:

```
{decimal number using a maximum of 10 columns} + 
" " + 
{decimal number taking a maximum of 10 columns}
```

I've tried

```
String outputFormat = "{0,-10:0.#####} {1,-10:0.#####}";
String output = String.Format(outputFormat, x, y);
```

But if `x` is `34059834.340598`, I don't get the output I want.

The first number takes more than 10 columns.

Is there a format string to force numbers to 10 columns? (Maybe show E notation if the n.m would be greater than 10 columns).

Comment: What do you mean bu "Columns"? What is the output you want from `34059834.340598` ?

Comment: I dont understand what you want. Can you show the inputs and the output you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [G specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString) for you number formating.

Something like this (untested) *should* work:

```
string tenCols = myDecimal.ToString("G10");
```

Or to be more inline with what you had before, I think this should do it:

```
String outputFormat = "{0,-10:G10} {1,-10:G10}";
String output = String.Format(outputFormat, x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double x = 34059834.340598
string displayX = x.ToString().Substring(0,10);
```

I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do what you want using format strings directly, but it's easy enough with string manipulation in code.

Comment: What if x was 100000000000000000.581. I don't want to lose information, just precision.

Comment: So if x was 100000000000000000.234 then you would want 1000000000 0000000023 then?  10 digits, space, 10 digits?  That seems weird.  Why not just always do scientific (E) notation?

Comment: I want scientific notation if the decimal number would be larger than 10 digits, else I want standard notation. String.Format() does this by default when the floating point value has lost precision on your hardware.